# How are Genetic Circuits Modelled?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, synthetic-biology, mathematical-models

I've read a recent Nature Methods paper by Moon [T.S. *et al*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23041931), in which a synthetic genetic circuit consisting of layered logic gates was created. For example, the paper, a circuit is modelled in Figure 4a. How is this circuit computationally modelled? Can you refer me to any graduate level texts on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following papers are a good starting point:

1. [René Thomas, Boolean formalization of genetic control circuits, *Journal of Theoretical Biology*, Volume 42, Issue 3, December 1973, Pages 563-585](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/4588055/) <= A classic paper in the field.
2. [D. Thieffry, Dynamical roles of biological regulatory circuits. *Brief
   Bioinform.* 2007 Jul;8(4):220-5.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17626067/)
3. [E. Remy, P. Ruet, From minimal signed circuits to the dynamics of Boolean
   regulatory networks. *Bioinformatics*. 2008 Aug 15;24(16):i220-6](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18689829/)

You can also have a look at [Computational Methods in Systems Biology, International Conference CMSB 2007, Edinburgh, Scotland, September 20-21, 2007. Proceedings](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-75140-3), specifically the chapter "Decision diagrams for the representation and analysis of logical models of genetic networks" by A. Naldi, D. Thieffry and C. Chaouiya.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive list of starting references.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest Uri Alon's *[An Introduction to Systems Biology](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/bookUri.html)*.

Personally, I learned using JJ Tyson's body of work and I would particullary recommend *[Sniffers, buzzers, toggles and blinkers: dynamics of regulatory and signaling pathways in the cell](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12648679)*

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation of Tyson's papers. I find his writing style to be quite clear and descriptive.